# Java output formatting for Strings

Tags: java, formatting

I was wondering if someone can show me how to use the format method for Java Strings.
For instance If I want the width of all my output to be the same

For instance, Suppose I always want my output to be the same

```
Name =              Bob
Age =               27
Occupation =        Student
Status =            Single
```

In this example, all the output are neatly formatted under each other; How would I accomplish this with the format method.

Comment: What do you actually want to know that [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format) and [format string documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) aren't showing you?

Comment: How do I set the the width, so my strings always output according to that width

Comment: you use the width specifier, e.g. %10s to be a width of 10.

Comment: You appear to have been given a requirement you are reluctant to workout for yourself. I can only assume this is homework?

Comment: Sort of, this is only one problem in the program Im working on for my class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## EDIT: This is an extremely primitive answer but I can't delete it because it was accepted. See the answers below for a better solution though

Why not just generate a whitespace string dynamically to insert into the statement.

So if you want them all to start on the 50th character...

```
String key = "Name =";
String space = "";
for(int i; i<(50-key.length); i++)
{space = space + " ";}
String value = "Bob\n";
System.out.println(key+space+value);
```

Put all of that in a loop and initialize/set the "key" and "value" variables before each iteration and you're golden. I would also use the `StringBuilder` class too which is more efficient.

Answer (score 149):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-20s= %s" , "label", "content" ));
```

- Where %s is a placeholder for you string.
- The '-' makes the result left-justified.
- 20 is the width of the first string

The output looks like this:

```
label               = content
```

As a reference I recommend [Javadoc on formatter syntax](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: You can also use `System.out.printf`, i.e. `System.out.printf("%-20s= %s" , "label", "content" );`

Comment: for this justified thingy+1

Comment: @JustinHarris Just remember that subsequent `System.out.printf` calls will not put newline characters between each output.  You can get around this by appending a `\n` character to the end of your format string though.

Comment: what if you wanted to make `"="` appear before the justification, but still have it exactly 20 characters between index 0 and the beginning of content? (My current solution is to just make a separate string including the`"="` and format that in instead. Is there a better solution?)

Comment: This answer is almost what OP is asking for. The exception (noted by @JosieThompson) is where the "=" sign ends up. You should do `System.out.println(String.format("%-20s %s" , "label =", "content" ));` to get what the OP wants. The difference is that you add the "=" sign to the label string. You're also able to call `System.out.format(...)` directly if you want. You only need to do it via `String` for constructs like `String str = String.format(...)`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a minimum of 4 characters, for instance,

```
System.out.println(String.format("%4d", 5));
// Results in "   5", minimum of 4 characters
```

Comment: actually wont that result in "0005"? since it is an integer argument. I am not sure if that same "number of spaces" argument works for strings though. (i.e. does %4s have a similar effect?) I can't say I've ever had to worry about my strings as I write them, but I use that argument for numbers all the time and I am pretty sure it results in leading 0s being added.

Comment: Nope! %4d will format with three leading spaces. To get leading zeros you would need %04d. I just tried this in IdeOne: http://ideone.com/dzNQU

Comment: ah yes, you're absolutely correct, that is the formatting string I used.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your updated question you can do

```
String[] lines = ("Name =              Bob\n" +
        "Age =               27\n" +
        "Occupation =        Student\n" +
        "Status =            Single").split("\n");

for (String line : lines) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" = +");
    System.out.printf("%-19s %s%n", parts[0] + " =", parts[1]);
}
```

prints

```
Name =              Bob
Age =               27
Occupation =        Student
Status =            Single
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     @Override
     public String toString() {
          return String.format("%15s /n %15d /n %15s /n %15s", name, age, Occupation, status);
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Amol. Instead of just adding a code snippet, why don't you also add a small explanation of how it works?

Answer (score 0):

For decimal values you can use DecimalFormat

```
import java.text.*;

public class DecimalFormatDemo {

   static public void customFormat(String pattern, double value ) {
      DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
      String output = myFormatter.format(value);
      System.out.println(value + "  " + pattern + "  " + output);
   }

   static public void main(String[] args) {

      customFormat("###,###.###", 123456.789);
      customFormat("###.##", 123456.789);
      customFormat("000000.000", 123.78);
      customFormat("$###,###.###", 12345.67);  
   }
}
```

and output will be:

```
123456.789  ###,###.###   123,456.789
123456.789  ###.##        123456.79
123.78      000000.000    000123.780
12345.67    $###,###.###  $12,345.67
```

For more details look here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html