# Field widths and strings

Tags: java

I am trying to print something out that is a string. it looks like this:

```
c.println("Item"+"Price");
```

I would like to have field widths instead out printing out the spaces myself as there are more lines that will be like this and I want to be as efficient as possible.

I am using java in a program call java ready to program.
any answer will be a great help as I have just started to learn java.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean field widths? Do you mean padded strings?

Comment: What is the declaration for `c`? If it is a `PrintStream`, then you can us the `format()` method, which is similar to C's `printf()` function.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible with de println, but you can use the String format function

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-20s= %s" , "label", "content" ));
```

see the same post: [Java output formatting for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings)