# How to format string output, so that columns are evenly centered?

Tags: java

In my java class we wrote a card program in which you choose a "secret card", and at the end it tells you what your secret card was. I am only having one issue, and that is formatting the output. As of right now, when it prints the fist column is even but the 2nd and 3rd are not. My teacher said to use spaces, but I have tried this and does not work. I know there is a way to format it but am unsure. The output looks like this:

```
     Column 0           Column 1           Column 2
    ________________________________________________
     3 of Spades    3 of Diamonds  Ace of Diamonds
     9 of Diamonds    2 of Diamonds   10 of Diamonds
   Ace of Spades   10 of Hearts King of Clubs
     6 of Clubs    4 of SpadesQueen of Hearts
     5 of Diamonds    2 of Hearts    7 of Clubs
     2 of Spades Jack of Diamonds    3 of Hearts
     5 of Hearts    4 of Hearts    7 of Diamonds
```

My output code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CardTrick {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

/* declare and initialize variables */
int column = 0, i = 0;
String name = " ";
String playAgain = " ";
String seeDeck = " ";

/* Declare a 52 element array of cards */
Card[] deck = new Card[52];

/* Declare a 7 by 3 array to receive the cards dealt to play the trick */
Card [][] play = new Card[7][3];

/* Declare a Scanner object for input */
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

If you want I can post the entire code, but I was trying not to post a lot. I greatly appreciate any help, being I am new to Java.

Comment: Please post the full loop code.

Comment: The easiest way could be add tabs (`'\t'`) between columns for them to match

Comment: @nem That depends on the length of each one... Some may be too long for tab to work

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper yes, but in that case he could look at the output and add test how many tabs would make the columns match.

Comment: Very easy to google this, and it turned up a previous Stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings

Comment: @nem hmmmmm, Im worried about the words like diamonds vs hearts. OP, I'll have an answer up in a minute, let me just finish typing

Comment: I would use a GUI utility for this, such as Swing, which is very easy to use, unless the assignment is to use only console output for the program.

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper yes, you are correct, that is why i said it **could** be the easiest way

Comment: If you change the picture cards names to only one letter like `A` instead of `Ace` and `J` instead of `Jack`, printing with tabs should work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm also going with the "format" suggestion, but mine is a little different.

In your program, you're relying on your card's `toString`. So make that formatted in a fixed length, and then you can use them anywhere and they will take up the same space.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format( "%5s of %-8s", rank, suit );
}
```

When you print this out, you'll have all your cards aligned on the "of" part, which I think is what you were going for in your first output column.

The "%5s" part right-aligns the rank in a field 5 characters wide, and the "%-8s" part left-aligns the suit in a field 8 characters wide (which means there are additional spaces to the right if the suit is shorter than 8 characters).

Answer (score 14):

You use something similar to what you are probably using right now. It looks like you are printing out using `System.out.print();` right? If so, you can use `System.out.printf();` along with `%#`. Let me explain.

It looks like you want to print out something that looks like this.

```
Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
12           23           1234
```

Well, the easy way to solve for that would be like this.

```
  int c1 = 12;
  int c2 = 23;
  int c3 = 1234;

  System.out.printf("%-22s%-22s%-22s\n","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3");
  System.out.printf("%-22d%-22d%-22d\n",c1,c2,c3);
```

Let's explain what is going on here, there's a lot of stuff happening. First, whenever you see a `%` sign in `System.out.printf()`, it means a special (formatting in this case) action is about to follow.

Now, let's look at the parameters of the method. The way `System.out.printf()` works is by specifying the format of the output in the first parameter. Then, the actual outputs are the following parameters. Do you see how it starts by specifying the format with `"%-22s%-22s%-22s\n"`? Then, it actually outputs them, separated by commas? That's IMO the easiest way to format.

Lastly, let's look some more at that special action thing I mentioned earlier. You see how there are letters and numbers and `-` after the `%`? Those all serve purposes too. [--HERE--](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/) is a good place to learn more but I'll give you the basic rundown.

First, the negative sign specifies which side will receive **padding**, padding is the space between the columns that makes them look pretty. Since it is negative, it will be on the right side, (FYI, if there was no sign there, padding would be on the left) so it will print out your output, then add spaces to the right... but how many spaces?

That's where that number comes in. The 17's you see are how many spaces there will be subtracted from the length of the output. Long story short, it will plainly and simply make sure each output starts and ends at the same place. The only catch is, make sure that the number, 22, is longer than the maximum possible String. I see the longest one possible would be `Queen of Diamonds` so anything bigger than 19 should do it, I chose 22 cuz it looked better IMO.

Next is the letter, that letter, as you can see, changes between the 2 output statements. In this case, one says s, the other says d. Easy way to solve this is, if your output is a String, use s, if it's and int (I don't think you will need it, I just had to for my example cuz mine were ints), use d.

Comment: Thank you, and I did do research online and in my book. I even looked at the website provided, but the explanations were confusing to me and I did not understand the way they explain it. I want to learn and understand the material, so I appreciate you taking the time to type all of this out. Through out researching I saw the string format but had no idea how to use is appropriately. Again, thank you a lot.

Comment: Understanding output format specifications such as `%*s` are vital to your whole future in many programming languages. It's not simple, but if you can spend time now getting your head round it that will pay back later. It's worth playing with some simple code for a while, to get the hang of it all. After that, you could tackle format specifications for input!

Comment: Thank you, it is nice when someone gives helpful advice and is not rude.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

Since you know the longest `String` you will have is `"Queen of Diamonds"`, you can base your separation on its length. The way you would do this is, for each current string, add spaces to it until its length matches the length of `"Queen of Diamonds"`. Then you add whatever separation you want, for example a tab (`"\t"`).

Here is a sample program:

```
static String[] cards = { "3 of Spades", "3 of Diamonds", "Ace of Diamonds",
            "9 of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds", "10 of Diamonds",
            "Ace of Spades", "10 of Hearts", "King of Clubs",
            "6 of Clubs", "4 of Spades", "Queen of Hearts",
            "5 of Diamonds", "2 of Hearts", "7 of Clubs",
            "2 of Spades", "Jack of Diamonds", "3 of Hearts",
            "5 of Hearts", "4 of Hearts", "7 of Diamonds" };

static String getSeparation(int len) {
     String longest = "Queen of Diamonds";
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     // add spaces to match the longest string
     for(int i = 0; i < longest.length() - len; i++) {
         sb.append(" ");
     }
     sb.append("\t"); // add separation tab
     return sb.toString();
 }

static void print() {
     for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 3) {
         System.out.println(cards[i] + getSeparation(cards[i].length()) +
                            cards[i + 1] + getSeparation(cards[i + 1].length()) +
                            cards[i + 2] + getSeparation(cards[i + 2].length()));
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print();
}
```

Output:

```
3 of Spades         3 of Diamonds       Ace of Diamonds     
9 of Diamonds       2 of Diamonds       10 of Diamonds      
Ace of Spades       10 of Hearts        King of Clubs       
6 of Clubs          4 of Spades         Queen of Hearts     
5 of Diamonds       2 of Hearts         7 of Clubs          
2 of Spades         Jack of Diamonds    3 of Hearts         
5 of Hearts         4 of Hearts         7 of Diamonds
```

A shorter solution would be to use [**`String.format`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or `System.out.printf` to format the output:

```
static String[] cards = { "3 of Spades", "3 of Diamonds",
        "Ace of Diamonds", "9 of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds",
        "10 of Diamonds", "Ace of Spades", "10 of Hearts", "King of Clubs",
        "6 of Clubs", "4 of Spades", "Queen of Hearts", "5 of Diamonds",
        "2 of Hearts", "7 of Clubs", "2 of Spades", "Jack of Diamonds",
        "3 of Hearts", "5 of Hearts", "4 of Hearts", "7 of Diamonds" };

static void print() {
    int spacingSeparation = 3;                   // number of spaces between columns
    int longest = "Queen of Diamonds".length();  // length of the widest column
    int spacing = longest + spacingSeparation;   // total spacing
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 3) {
        System.out.print(String.format(
                "%-" + spacing + "s%-" + spacing + "s%-" + spacing + "s\n",  // format
                cards[i], cards[i + 1], cards[i + 2]));                      // values
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print();
}
```

Output:

```
3 of Spades         3 of Diamonds       Ace of Diamonds     
9 of Diamonds       2 of Diamonds       10 of Diamonds      
Ace of Spades       10 of Hearts        King of Clubs       
6 of Clubs          4 of Spades         Queen of Hearts     
5 of Diamonds       2 of Hearts         7 of Clubs          
2 of Spades         Jack of Diamonds    3 of Hearts         
5 of Hearts         4 of Hearts         7 of Diamonds
```

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend putting tabs in between the columns. The only problem with using tabs would be that the lengths of the strings can vary, so the number of tabs you use might change.

However, the nice thing is that you know the longest string is 'Queen of Diamonds' and you can adjust accordingly with that. My guess is two or three tab spaces will be enough, but you can play with it.

In other words, your code would look something like this:

```
// loop to deal card
for(row = 0; row <7; row++){
   for(col = 0; col < 3; col++){
    play[row][col] = deck[card];
    System.out.print(play[row][col].toString() + "\t\t\t"); // Change here.
    card++;
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: How do you change the length of the tab? When I do it Column 0 and 1 are right but really far apart. I have never seen the "tab"method used.

Comment: Well, you can change the number of tabs used. Maybe you need to change `\t\t\t` to `\t\t`. That's what I meant by you may have to play a bit.

Comment: Tabs may (admittedly) not be the best way. @WeatherVane linked to a good one in the comments of your question, that might help too.