# Return Multiple Arrays Using for Loop Inside toString Class

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, tostring

This is what I have so far. What this program basically does is take user input(their social security numbers), verifies that their input is in the proper format (XXX-XX-XXXX), adds the verified input to the arrays list. Now the final step is to create a toString() method that will return a human readable String representation of all social security numbers added to the array. This method must use a for loop, and must print 1 social security number entry per line. For example:

"The Social Security Numbers you entered are:
       345-43-5674
       456-62-8435
       910-70-0053"

```
package SSNServerStorage;

public class SSNArray
{
    private String[] SSNNumber;
    private int arrayCount;

    public SSNArray(){
        SSNNumber = new String[300];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public SSNArray(int arraySize){
        SSNNumber = new String[arraySize];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public String[] getSSNNumber(){
        return SSNNumber;
    }

    public int getArrayCount(){
        return arrayCount;
    }

    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
        return SSNFormat.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    }

    public String addSSN(String SSNFormat){
        if (validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
            return SSNNumber[arrayCount++] = SSNFormat;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        System.out.println("The Social Security Numbers you entered are:");

        for()
        {
            //
            //
            //
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your for loop inside the test class

Comment: Try to use StringBuilder

Comment: Have you tried anything or is this just a request to write code for you? You should not print the output in the `toString` method. That method should be used to create and return the String representation of an object, not print it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java output formatting for Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings)

Comment: @fabian I think the question is just misusing the word "print", but a clarification from OP might be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `String` to concatenate all the SSNumbers.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String str = "The Social Security Numbers you entered are:\n";
    for(int x=0; x< arrayCount; x++)
        str += SSNumber[x] + "\n";
    return str;
}
```

Since it is a `toString()` method, you will want to return the string representation of the class instead of doing `println()`.

Comment: **Never** use `String += String` in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Andreas This looks like a school assignment, according to my knowledge in universities and colleges, they don't expect you to use StringBuilder. String is suffice for them.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks dude, changed.

Comment: You may have a point on "school assignment", it's just very bad form, and hits a nerve. ;-)

Comment: You got my up-vote. Add `\n` after `:`, and it's more common to use `i` as index variable.

Answer (score 4):

Your `toString` method doesn't have correct signature, it should return `String`. This should do what you need:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The Social Security Numbers you entered are:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
        sb.append(SSNNumber[i]).append("\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Also remember to use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @Andreas you're right, thanks for heads up - didn't notice that upon first reading. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder strbul = new StringBuilder()
    for(int i=0;i<SSNNumber.length;i++)
            {
                strbul.append(SSNNumber[i]).append("\n");
            }
return strbul.toString();
```

Comment: Loop should be limited to `arrayCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate :

```
@Override
public String toString(){
String s = "The Social Security Numbers you entered are:\n";
    for(int i =0; i < SSNNumber.length; i ++)
        s +=SSNNumber[i]+"\n";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: **Never** use `String += String` in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Also it looks like not every element in the array needs to contain a String.

Comment: Loop should be limited to `arrayCount`.