# Return statement in a toString class

Tags: java

So I have a Card class that looks like this:

```
public class Card
{
    //instance variables
    private String faceValue; //the face value of the card
    private String suit; //the suit of the card
    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Card(int aValue, int aSuit)
{
    faceValue = ranks[aValue];
    suit = suits[aSuit];
}

//getters
/**
 * Getter for faceValue.
 */
public String getFaceValue()
{
    return faceValue;
}

/**
 * Getter for suit.
 */
public String getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}
//end of getters

//methods
/**
 * This method returns a String representation of a Card object.
 * 
 * @param   none
 * @return  String 
 */
public String toString()
{
    return "A card: " + faceValue + " of " + suit;
}
}
```

And a Deck class that looks like this:

```
public class Deck
{
    //instance variables
    private Card[] deck;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Deck
 */
public Deck() 
{
    deck = new Card[52];

    int cardCount = 0; //number of cards created so far.
    for (int aSuit = 0; aSuit < 4; aSuit++ ) 
    {
        for ( int aValue = 0; aValue < 13; aValue++ ) {
            deck[cardCount] = new Test(aValue, aSuit);
            cardCount++;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * String representation.
 */
public String toString()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        String v = deck[i].getFaceValue();
        String s = deck[i].getSuit();
        return "Dealt a card: " + v + " of " + s + ".";
    }
}
}
```

My toString method in the deck shows an error "missing return statement". How do  change the return statement while still allowing it to print the card details after every loop?

Comment: If you return in a loop you only get the very first element of the list

Comment: You should read the JavaDoc on `toString()` to see what it is meant for (which isn't to produce log statements) - as such `Card.toString()` is fine since it is a representation of a single card but `Deck.toString()` is not since it doesn't represent the deck but rather some action (or at least "Dealt a card ..." implies so). Instead you'll probably want to provide a method that either directly prints the log statements or returns a list of strings for later use.

Comment: First thing, your toString is not going to do what you want even if you did not have that error. You need to create a variable that aggregates the string, and return it once at the end of the function.. As it is it will run through the first iteration of the loop and return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Multiple Arrays Using for Loop Inside toString Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787238/return-multiple-arrays-using-for-loop-inside-tostring-class)

Comment: Also consider: you could just print `deck[i]` since you've defined the toString of the Card

Comment: @criket_007 Yes that is a solution.. but a really bad one.. never EVER use += on string especially in a loop.. it is VERY inefficient.. use a string builder, or in a threaded application stringBuffer..

Answer (score 2):

Code you wrote will only return 0th element from deck array. it should be like:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        String v = deck[i].getFaceValue();
        String s = deck[i].getSuit();
        sb.append("Dealt a card: ").append(v).append(" of ").append(s).append(".\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your `toString` method has the return type String.
Java checks for execution paths. What if the `for` loop ends and never returns anything?

Although you may have hardcoded that logic, but Java compiler does not do a statistical analysis of that.  Hence it must return a type String which is sure to execute if nothing else works.

This will work:

```
public String toString()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        String v = deck[i].getFaceValue();
        String s = deck[i].getSuit();
        return "Dealt a card: " + v + " of " + s + ".";
    }
    return "";
}
```

But I guess what you want is this:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        String v = deck[i].getFaceValue();
        String s = deck[i].getSuit();
        returnValue.append("Dealt a card: " + v + " of " + s + ".");
    }
    return returnValue.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u just want to print all the cards infos, u can use

```
public String toString(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
    String v = deck[i].getFaceValue();
    String s = deck[i].getSuit();
    System.out.println( "Dealt a card: " + v + " of " + s + ".");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have no idea why I didn't think of this a long time ago. I'm so used to toString methods only returning stuff. Thank you so much!