# For Loop Depreciation Java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class Machine 
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
  int DEP = 4000;
  System.out.println ("YEAR     DEPRECIATION      END-OF-YEAR          ACCUMULATED");
  System.out.println ("                              VALUE       DEPRECIATION");
  System.out.println ("------   ------------      -----------    -------------");

  for (int year = 1; year <= 7; year++)
  {
     System.out.println (year + "           " + DEP + "              " + (28000 - (DEP * year)) + "            " + (DEP * year));
  }
 }
}
```

[Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs2cm.png)

Hey guys i made this program for my java class and everything in it works but im just stuck on one thing.
You see if you look in the picture the top part is supposed to be my output, but the bottom one is the one im actually getting. Theres some problem with the numbers all the way at the bottom right under Accumulated Depreciation. I wanted to know how I can fix this.

Comment: The best answer is to use `System.out.printf(...)` or one of its variants, and I've closed your question as a duplicate, but note that the accepted answer to the dup is not the best, and others, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4418410/522444) are far better.

Comment: You should in your title ask about the technical problem, not about the requirement.

Comment: i dont see tthe question