# Referring to Specific Object

Tags: java

I'm trying to refer to a certain object in an ArrayList that is found using this function. Once found, I'm trying to print some information about it to make sure that I'm grabbing the right object.

So far it finds the object, but I'm not sure how to print the information of the object found.

My objects are formatted like this

plushieSpec (Brand brand, Fabric fabric, Color color, Species species) -> plushie (String UPC, double price, plushieSpec spec) -> Inventory

```
public static Object findUPC(String a)  
{    
    for (int i=0; i <inventory.size(); i++) {
        if (inventory.get(i).UPC.equals(a)){
             System.out.println("Product found: " + plushieSpec.species);   
        }
    }
    return "No product with this UPC"; 
}
```

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method for your objects.

Comment: Your code should not be returning the product from this method. It will always return "No product with this UPC", event if it runs the println. Please include the code for plushieSpec and plushie as well.

Comment: What exactly is you problem? Are there compilation errors? Do you not get the correct information printed? Please clarify your problem. To get a `String` representation, you probably want to override the [`toString()`-Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

Comment: Generally you should not be dealing with "Object" instances.  You should have a class that represents the thing you are finding (in this case a Plushie class).  If the inventory contains multiple object types have them adhere to an interface and declare inventory to contain those.  Then in your concrete classes implement toString() and call it in your print method.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `toString()` method of your class and give the object reference in `System.out.print(obj)`. For formatting, you should use [System.out.format(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) or [String.format(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), whichever suits you better.

Possible duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings).

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(object) applies object.toString() method that prints type info of the object (Eg: com.foo.objectType@2f92e0f4). To print actual method variable you have to override the toString() method like this

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   // return species variables appended with +.
}
```