# Output Format Java

Tags: java, format, pretty-print

I have an assignment Q and I have most of it done but need the output to be neater. I need to ask user to choose num of rows between 3-10 and num of columns between 5-10.

1. but the output needs to have the number spaced evenly apart but I can't get it working!!?
2. I need to validate the users input... how?

---

Sample Code:

```js
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter number of rows between the range of 3 to 10: ");

int count1 = s.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter number of Columns between the range of 5 to 10: ");
int count2 = s.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <= count1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= count2; j++) {

        System.out.print((i * j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

}
}
```

I have attached image showing output and what I need.
[image]

Comment: This is some interesting JavaScript.

Comment: You could use `\t` for a tab instead of a space when printing.

Comment: Also, validating the users input is simply checking if the input is, in this case, between 3 and 10, if it is not, display an error message, i.e. `That number is not valid. Please enter a valid number` and ask again. hint, use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would much rather leave this as a comment, but yay for less than 50 reputation. Take a look at the following links, they should provide you with some insight:

A similar stackoverflow question

[Java output formatting for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings)

and the Java documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Hope they help you.

**EDIT:**

In answer to your second question, the comment suggesting a loop would be a good place to start. Something similar to the following:

```
System.out.print("Please enter number of rows between the range of 3 to 10: ");
int count1 = s.nextInt();

while (count1 < 3 || count1 > 10) {
    System.out.print("That is not a valid input. Try again: ");
    count1 = s.nextInt();
}
```

And of course the same for `count2`. You could also make that a separate function and pass `count1` and `count2` to it separately to reduce duplicate code. The loop condition here `count1 < 3 || count1 > 10` will continue to prompt the user for input until it is within the acceptable range.