# Android format properly spaces

Tags: android, listview, format, string.format

I have a ListView, and I use toString to show my object in the ListView.

```
private String displayToUI() {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
    format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false); //if overall = "X.0", the format will print "X"
    switch (FORMAT_TYPE) {
        case 0: // i.e "Guy - 5 | Host | Attending"
            String membership;
            String attending;
            if (this._playerishost == 1)
                membership = "Host";
            else
                membership = "Guest";
            if (this._playerisattending == 1)
                attending = "Attending";
            else
                attending = "Not Attending";
            return this._playername + " - " + format.format(this._playeroverall) + " | " + membership + " | " + attending;
        case 1: // i.e "Guy - 5"
            return this._playername + " - " + format.format(this._playeroverall);
    }
    return "0";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return displayToUI();
}
```

In case **FORMAT_TYPE=0** , I want to use format, to display the objects properly, so each column will be in his place, and the function will display the objects like a table

this is the output right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvvNH.png

**EDIT:**

I used String.format (@Pynnie 's answer) and the code line is now:

```
                return String.format("%-20s %-4s | %-5s | %s", this._playername, format.format(this._playeroverall), membership, attending);
```

but the output doesn't fit, and it look like the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEn27.png

also, my listview adapter code:

```
public void editListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Player> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DBHandler.getNameListGeneral());
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.db_list_view);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
}
```

Comment: Place your xml and your adaptar code here so we can have an idea on what you are doing.

Comment: @Rob Done! edited my post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to format your Strings properly, using `String.format()` . A proper way of using this is already documented  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418376/6868843)

Comment: I am trying to use String.format(), but it still doesn't fit, I edited the question and added a picture

Comment: passing "%-10s %-6s | %-10s | %s" as the first argument in String.format() should do the trick. The second and third spacing must be a little bigger

Answer (score 1):

Use a monospace font, i.e. a font where an "i" has the same width as e.g. an "m". This together with pynnies answer should work

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to format the string you could try to modify the layout xml for the list items.

Use a LinearLayout with three textviews and horizontal orientation.