# How to format my numbers so that the are aligned to the right?

Tags: java, formatting

```
Iterator iterator = indexMap.keySet().iterator();

                   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iterator.next().toString();

                        System.out.print(key + ":    ");

                        ArrayList<Integer> values = indexMap.get(key);
                        Iterator<Integer> n  = values.iterator();

                        while(n.hasNext()){

                            int line = n.next();

                         System.out.print("%8d", line);


                        }
                        System.out.print("\n");

                    }
```

please realize that Im printing words from a map, and each key maps to an Array list. I want to print the key, followed by the numbers in its array list. Im doing this so far with two while loops to interate through each.

input:    5       9
int:    6       16      17
integer:    8       14
java:    1
main:    4
n:    16      20      21      23
new:    5
nextInt:    9
num:    6       9       10
out:    8       11
print:    8
println:    11
public:    2       4       16
return:    25
returns:    14
static:    4       16
takes:    14
the:    15
toBinary:    10      14      16

Comment: I'd like so that the numbers start printing like 10 spaces from the very beginning of the word, not the end of the word so that the all line up on the same column.

Comment: You may also wish to give some consistency to the keys. Try something like `System.out.printf("%12s", key);` and `System.out.printf("%8d", line);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java output formatting for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings)

Comment: KevinO your method worked!