# format a string for a toString() function in java with tab and new line

Tags: java, string

I am trying to have a string that when i print it, has multiple lines and different left indents.

```
String test = "Zone 0:" +
             "Gear{" + "gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" + weight}" +
              "Zone 1:" + 
                "Gear{" + "gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" +weight}"; 
System.out.println(test);
```

**Expected Output: (without the dashes but with a left indent)**

Zone 0:

------Gear{gearType=RAIN_JACKET, weight=HIGH}

Zone 1:

------Gear{gearType=SHELTER, weight=HIGH}

Comment: Hi, Can you please show us your attempt?

Comment: You might refer to answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418308/java-output-formatting-for-strings)

Comment: Note that in real Java code, this would be a seriously annoying string format because it takes up way too much space and will cause bizarre line wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `"\n"` new line character and `"\t"` for tab. Like:

```
final String test = "Zone 0:\n" + "\tGear{" + "gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" + weight +"}\n" + "Zone 1:\n"
        + "\tGear{" + "gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" + weight + "}\n";
```

As well as after weight there should be `+` sign and a double quote `"`. (as in above String)

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i wanted, thank you. is there are way to use the "\t" more than once to double indent a line?

Comment: place it twice like \t\t

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "\n" for new line and "\t" for tabulation space :

```
String test  = "Zone 0:\n" + "\tGear{" + "gearType=" + 
                gearType + ", weight=" + "weight}\n" + 
                "Zone 1:\n" + "\tGear{" + "gearType=" + 
                gearType + ", weight=" + "weight}";
```

output :

```
Zone 0:
   Gear{gearType=test, weight=weight}
Zone 1:
   Gear{gearType=test, weight=weight}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also refer to the official [Formatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). There you'll get all the other options and details for formatting a String in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you'd want the lines to use the appropriate line terminator for your platform, i.e. `\r\n` for Windows and `\n` for Linux.

There are two ways to do that:

- Use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()):

  ```
  String test = "Zone 0:" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "      Gear{gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" + weight + "}" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "Zone 1:" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "      Gear{gearType=" + gearType + ", weight=" + weight + "}" + System.lineSeparator();
  ```
- Use [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and the `%n` format specifier:

  ```
  String test = String.format("Zone 0:%n" +
                              "      Gear{gearType=%s, weight=%s}%n" +
                              "Zone 1:%n" +
                              "      Gear{gearType=%s, weight=%s}%n",
                              gearType, weight, gearType, weight);
  ```

I'd recommend the second approach, since it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

May be an idea to rather use a `StringBuilder` (though from what I understand the Java compiler uses `StringBuilder` under the hood for String concatenation), so it really becomes more of a readability issue.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()
   .append(System.lineSeparator()).append("Zone 0:")
   .append(System.lineSeparator()).append("\tGear{gearType=").append(gearType).append(", weight=").append(weight).append("}")
   .append(System.lineSeparator()).append("Zone 1:")
   .append(System.lineSeparator()).append("\tGear{gearType=").append(gearType).append(", weight=").append(weight).append("}");
 System.out.print(output.toString());
```

For **newlines** it's good practice to use `System.lineSeparator()`